# Difference between page view load time and browser page load time in Azure application insights for a SPA

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a web app in Azure (it's a SPA using Angular.js) and I want to gather the client usage statistics. There are 2 pre-defined metrics to gather the usage statistics - Browser Page Load Time and Page View Load Time?

What exactly is the  difference between **page view load time** and **browser page load time** in application insights? From what I gather is that Browser Page Load is the time taken to Load the site for the first time and Page View Load time is the average of time taken to load each page. But since I am using a SPA is there really a difference are they denoting the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how these are calculated in the API according to the comment in
[**`PageViewPerformanceManager.ts`**](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/2.6.2/extensions/applicationinsights-analytics-js/src/JavaScriptSDK/Telemetry/PageViewPerformanceManager.ts#L29-L48):

```js
/*
  * http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#processing-model
  *  |-navigationStart
  *  |             |-connectEnd
  *  |             ||-requestStart
  *  |             ||             |-responseStart
  *  |             ||             |              |-responseEnd
  *  |             ||             |              |
  *  |             ||             |              |         |-loadEventEnd
  *  |---network---||---request---|---response---|---dom---|
  *  |--------------------------total----------------------|
  * 
  *  total = The difference between the load event of the current document is completed and the first recorded timestamp of the performance entry : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings#duration
  *  network = Redirect time + App Cache + DNS lookup time + TCP connection time 
  *  request = Request time : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings#request_time
  *  response = Response time
  *  dom = Document load time : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document-load-timing-info
  *      = Document processing time : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/navigation-and-resource-timing/#document_processing
  *      + Loading time : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/navigation-and-resource-timing/#loading
  */
```

Comment: This link is outdated.  I assume that this is the correct one: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/75298bb9a72ca974c09cc40911ae3d97b74d519c/extensions/applicationinsights-analytics-js/src/JavaScriptSDK/Telemetry/PageViewPerformanceManager.ts#L30

Comment: The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/capture-page-load-times-application-insights/ seems to be the latest